# MAX31865 RTD converter will it acccept only floating inputs?

Tags: grounding, rtd

We intend to use MAX31865 for measuring resistance values. Since MAX31865 is RTD to digital converter, kindly clarify whether the MAX31865 will accept only floating inputs or it can be used with electrically grounded reference, i.e. can RTD -ve input of MAX31865 be grounded?.

Answer (score 0):

Datasheet  https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf

None of the 2,3,4 wire typical connections show grounded pins.  You can ask Tech Support at https://www.maximintegrated.com/en.html if it is possible. They are very heplful.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled in from Google. I have a MAX31865 on a PCB measuring a 2-wire PT1000 RTD. I didn't intend for the RTD to be grounded but the threads on the bulkhead SMA jack I was using cut through the paint on the panel.  As a result, the MAX31865 gave faults:

```
VREFIN- < 0.85 x VBIAS when FORCE- input switch is open
VRTDIN- < 0.85 x VBIAS when FORCE- input switch is open
```

However, the RTD reading and subsequent temperature conversion were correct. So I can say, in some instances, it *may* be OK to connect a grounded RTD to the MAX31865.